# Difference between state estimate data and odometry data

Tags: navigation, robot-pose-ekf

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying my hand at robot navigation. I am not able to comprehend, the following differences,

1. Difference in the odometry data from sources like wheel or visual and the output generated by state estimators like robot_pose_ekf packages. Because they both seem to have the same message format.
2. I am able to understand the transform between baselink and different sensor coordinate frames. But what is the difference between world, map, nav, odom and base_link frame. In some cases I find, base_footprint and base_stabilized coordinate frames too.
3. In the tf map, should there be one fixed frame and can odom_frame be made as fixed frame in the presence of /map or /world frame?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/218288/difference-between-state-estimate-data-and-odometry-data/) by [boon](https://answers.ros.org/users/21540/boon/) on ROS Answers with karma: 111 on 2015-09-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

1. Data from sources like wheel encoders or visual odometry can be noisy and might not be good enough. Therefore, [robot_pose_ekf](http://wiki.ros.org/robot_pose_ekf) combines measurements coming from different sources (like IMU, Wheel encoders, Visual Odometry) using EKF to provide a better estimate of the 3D pose of the robot.
2. [REP-105](http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0105.html) explains different coordinate frames. `base_footprint` is just a projection of `base_link` on the ground.
3. Yes.. `odom_frame` can be made a fixed frame in presence of other frames. I am not 100% sure about this. Can someone confirm this?

Hope it helps.

---

Originally posted by [Naman](https://answers.ros.org/users/11186/naman/) with karma: 1464 on 2015-09-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0